# C# General Library Structure

Tags: c#, class

I want to develop a library for communicating with a circuit via serial port. This circuit understands roughly 100 serial commands and returns a response string.

The commands are divided into 3 categories (settings, environment, and outputs) so I would like to use properties or some other means to nest the categories and methods within the overall class. Instead of throwing all the command methods under a single class, what would be the recommended way to nest them? I want to avoid the following at all costs, it would just be a mess:

```
public class CircuitLib
{
   ...
   // Methods.
   public string SettingCommand1(string command) {...}
   ...
   public string SettingCommand30(string command) {...}

   public string EnvironmentCommand1(string command) {...}
   ...
   public string EnvironmentCommand30(string command) {...}

   public string OutputCommand1(string command) {...}
   ...
   public string OutputCommand30(string command) {...}
}
```

It would be nice to be able to use properties to get to the specified category:

```
circuitLibInstance.GetSettingsProperty.OneOfTheSettingsMethods(stringCommand);
```

Any guidance would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could have:

```
public class Circuit
{
    // Initialize these in the constructor
    private readonly SettingCommands settings;
    private readonly EnvironmentCommands environment;
    private readonly OutputCommands output;

    public SettingCommands Settings { get { return settings; } }
    public EnvironmentCommands Environment { get { return environment; } }
    public OutputCommands Output { get { return output; } }
}

public class SettingCommands
{
    public string Foo(string command) { ... }
}
```

Then:

```
string result = instance.Settings.Foo("hello");
```

Is that what you were after?

Of course if all your command methods actually have the same structure, you might potentially want an enum, for example:

```
public enum SettingCommand { Foo, Bar, Baz }
public enum EnvironmentCommand { Alice, Bob, Charlie }
public enum OutputCommand { Ender, Bean, Alai }
```

then:

```
public class Circuit
{
    public string Execute(SettingCommand command, string data) { ... }
    public string Execute(EnvironmentCommand command, string data) { ... }
    public string Execute(OutputCommand command, string data) { ... }
}
```

and use as:

```
string result = instance.Execute(SettingCommand.Foo, "data");
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Jon. I initially considered something very similar but ran into a problem using the serial port. I created a `SerialPort` field and `string SendRecieve(string command)` method under the `Circuit` class but was unsure of the best way to call `string result = instance.Settings.Foo("hello");` using the `Circuit` instance's serial port. What would be the most elegant way to accomplish this? Add a `SerialPort` field and `SendRecieve`method to each command class and set them when the `Circuit` instance is constructed?

Comment: @Jon: It's not really clear what you mean - I've presented multiple approaches and it's not clear which one you're trying to use. If you're trying to use the `instance.Settings.Foo` version, then your `SendReceive` method would be in the `SettingCommands` class, not in `Circuit`.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion, I was looking at your first suggestion. I do need the `SerialPort` field and a public `SendRecieve` method in the `Circuit` class so I can send any text string (e.g. `cirInstance.SendRecieve(Console.ReadLine())`); this is mainly used in debugging. Then, I was thinking that I need a private `SerialPort` and `SendRecieve` in each of the settings classes? Do I set these when I construct the `Circuit` instance? I hope that makes sense, bare with me I'm a M.E. :/

Comment: @Jon: I would consider passing the `Circuit` into the `SettingCommand` constructor so you can delegate it that way. The `SettingCommand` is only a nicety really.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the command string has to be formatted in a very specific way.  If so I would abstract that knowledge so that it's encapsulated within your CircuitLib.  So I would probably have something like:

```
public class CircuitLib {
    public string SettingCommand1(int a, bool b, string c) {}
    public string SettingCommand2(bool a, double b) {}
    public string EnvironmentCommand2(string a, DateTime b) {}
    ...
}
```

The the individual methods are responsible for accepting the strongly typed data and creating the propertly formatted strings that get sent to the device.  In this case I don't see any problem with having a class with 100 methods as it is encapsulating a device with a very procedural interface that can understand 100 methods.

Alternatively, if you really want the interface you suggested you could do it easily enough like so:

```
public class CircuitLib {
    public SettingCircuitLib Settings {get; set;}
    public EnvironmentCircuitLib Environment {get; set;}
}

public class SettingCircuitLib {
    public string SettingCommand1(string command) {}
    public string SettingCommand2(string command) {}
}
```

then you'd just call it like so:

```
CircuitLibInstance.Settings.SettingCommand1(cmd);
CircuitLibInstance.Environment.EnvironmentCommand1(cmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I might approach it a little more 'fluent' like:

```
public class CircuitLib
{
    public CircuitSetting Setting { get; }
    public CircuitEnvironment Environment { get; }
    public CircuitOutput Command { get; }
}

//Obviously you need one for each type above
public class CircuitSetting
{
    CircutSettingCommand1 Command1 { get; }
    CircutSettingCommand30 Command30 { get; }
}
public class CircutSettingCommand1 
{
    Send(string command);
}
```

However you build the class structure, rigid like above, or some interfaces, etc, the goal is still the same.  Be able to write client code something like the following:

```
using(CircuitLib lib = new CircuitLib(...))
{
    lib.Setting.Command1.Send("Hello World");
}
```

This allows a user fewer choices to start with as the navigate down the structure.

Answer (score 0):

I would create your library as a static class that contains three instance classes like:

```
public class Settings 
{
     public string SettingCommand1(string command) {...}
     ...
     public string SettingCommand30(string command) {...}
}
public class Environment 
{
     public string EnvironmentCommand1(string command) {...}
     ...
     public string EnvironmentCommand30(string command) {...}
}
public class Output
{
     public string OutputCommand1(string command) {...}
     ...
     public string OutputCommand30(string command) {...}
}    
public static class CircuitLib
{
     public static Settings Settings = new Settings ();
     public static Environment Environment = new Environment ();
     public static Output Output  = new Output();
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
CircuitLib.Settings.SettingCommand1("input");
CircuitLib.Environment.EnvironmentCommand30("input");
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that there can be multiple circuits so, unfortunately, a static class won't work.